# ASP Classic with SQL - missing operator

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am trying to get this piece of SQL functioning:

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM [GROUP] INNER JOIN ubuser ON group.grp_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID INNER JOIN grpMembersLink ON grpMembersLink.grp_ID = [Group].grp_ID WHERE [Group].grp_ID = " & grpID & ""
```

However it is not functioning and I am unsure as to why, can anyone see something wrong with this that I am missing?

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'group.grp_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID INNER JOIN grpMembersLink ON grpMembersLink.grp_ID = [Group].grp_I'.

Comment: How are you passing the value of usrID in to the page that has your query on it? Are you posting a form, getting from session, etc?

Comment: Please please please use ADODB parameters to avoid the injection possibility!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already in ASP mode so use string concatenation (*with `&`*)

```
readsql = "SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID  WHERE usr_ID = '" & usrID & "' ORDER BY pos_date DESC, pos_time DESC"
```

But keep in mind that you must sanitize the input if it comes from a user, or your code will be prone to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I think that worked but I am getting this error now and have no idea why?

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: @Jayyf9 what datatype is `usr_ID` in your database ?

Comment: if it is numeric then you might have to remove the `'` around it. Like this `WHERE usr_ID = " & usrID & " ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do string concatenation so add `&` before and after `<%=usrID%>`